# How to solve php versions mis-match (Centos 6)

Tags: php, dependencies, centos6

I am running a Centos 6 server. After some non-successful attempts to install php 7.2 I have dependencies problems (trying yum update php):
So what is the best and safest way to reinstall php?

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.40-1.w6 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-1.w6 for package: php56w-phpdbg-5.6.40- 
1.w6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56w-phpdbg-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
       Requires: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-1.w6
       Removing: php56w-common-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
           php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-1.w6
       Obsoleted By: php-common-7.2.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Not found
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While upgrade from 3rd party repository to remi should work smoothly (this being a best effort), you have been hitten by an (old) issue, **php-dbg** should obsolete **php56w-phpdbg**. This have ben fixed, and will be in next update.

For now, simply remove this debugger before the upgrade.

```
yum remove php56w-phpdbg
yum update
yum install php-dbg
```

As usually, see the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

P.S. webtatic seems a dead project, no update for ~1 year, so everybody should migrate to a better alternative, such as "remi" repository.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install remi repository for installing php 7.2. You can also switch between versions of php.

**For installing**

```
 wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
 wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
 rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

**For enabling php 7.2**

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
```

Have a look [here](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/12/04/Install-PHP-7.2-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora) also [here](https://dev.to/kevinmel2000/how-to-upgrade-php-5-6-to-php-7-2-on-centos-6-7-4lbb)  for more details

Comment: Thank you, but when I run yum php update, I am getting a dependency error (see above). Of cause the php -v still shows 5.6.40 after that...

Comment: ooo,  Remi Collet has answered that part to solve dependency error